# Docker registry mirror

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to set a docker mirror to be the default mirror to pull/push images.

As per documentation I already set the file /etc/docker/daemon.json with the following:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://localregistry"]
}
```

Then I try the following:

```
docker login localregistry
docker pull localregistry/image:tag > it works
docker pull image:tag > doesn't work
```

I'm always getting `"no basic auth credentials error"` from the docker daemon, but from the registry log I get `err.code="manifest unknown" err.detail="unknown tag"`

Any idea?
I'm using docker version 19.03.08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker login localregistry
```

First, I hope this is changing the name for the question, because the registry name `localregistry` will not work...

```
docker pull localregistry/image:tag > it works
```

The fact that this works indicates that you likely have a registry name with a `.` or `:` in the hostname. Otherwise docker would try to pull `localregistry/image:tag` from the `localregistry` user on Docker Hub.

```
docker pull image:tag > doesn't work
```

This should always work, failures should be transparent to the user if it's really a mirror of Docker Hub. What happens is it resolves that name to `docker.io/library/image:tag`, first tries to pull from `localregistry/library/image:tag`, and any error falls back to a pull from Docker Hub, and any error there finally shows to the user.

Most likely the issue is that you didn't include `library` as the repo name for your image in the local registry.

If you are using this to include images that don't exist on Docker Hub, then I would skip the mirror and simply refer to the mirror explicitly. Doing otherwise creates many opportunities for nonintuitive failures that aren't easy to see. E.g. a stale image can be pushed to your mirror in place of an upstream image, and Docker will stop pulling updates from upstream. And because any mirror errors fall back to Hub, if you use an image name that you have no control over upstream, someone else could take that name on Hub and begin injecting unknown or even malicious images into your server.

If this doesn't answer your question, then I'd recommend using your question with actual image names and error messages from the logs showing what specifically failed (you can mask out part of the registry name of necessary).

Comment: I missed to say that this is an air gapped environment so first I downloaded the images and then I uploaded them to my registry. What I want to achieve is to be able to pull any image in my registry without having to prepend my registry url in all the images.

Comment: @ricosega trying to use the mirror to avoid specifying the registry name causes more problems than it solves. This shouldn't be something you are constantly typing, use a compose file or kubernetes manifest.